# islistinlist function for coldfusion 11

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I have this function and running flawless on coldfusion 2016 and lucee but wen i run in cf11, it fails.

i am trying to understand how can i make it work with cf11

```
private any function isListInList(list1, list2, returnBoolean = true){
        var rv = false; 
        var matches = [];
        listToArray(list1).each(
            function(element) { 
                if(listToArray(list2).containsNoCase(element)){
                    rv = true;
                    arrayAppend(matches, element);
                }
            }
        );
        return arguments.returnBoolean ? rv : matches;
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "it fails"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This version of your function will compile and run on CF11

```js
private any function isListInList(list1, list2, returnBoolean = true){
    var rv = false; 
    var matches = [];
    var arr1 = listToArray(list1);
    var arr2 = listToArray(list2);
    arr1.each(
        function(element) { 
            if(arr2.findNoCase(element)){
                rv = true;
                arrayAppend(matches, element);
            }
        }
    );
    return arguments.returnBoolean ? rv : matches;
}
```

This version that uses a `for()` loop will be optimized for large arrays since it will short circuit the loop when it finds a match and you just want the boolean back.

```js
private any function isListInList(list1, list2, returnBoolean = true){
    var arr1 = listToArray(list1);
    var arr2 = listToArray(list2);
    var rv = false; 
    var matches = [];
    for( var element in arr1 )  {
        if(arr2.findNoCase(element)){
            if( returnBoolean ) {
                return true;
            } else {
                arrayAppend(matches, element);
            }
        }
    }
    return arguments.returnBoolean ? false : matches;
}
```